# fetching https links only

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-crawler

i can get the links but Idk how to filter https only

Answer (score -1):

To parse HTML use html parser, e.g. BeautifulSoup. To extract desired `<a>` elements, you can use CSS selector `'a[href^="https"]'` (Selects every `<a>` element whose `href` attribute value begins with "https"):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://sayamkanwar.com/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('a[href^="https"]'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://sayamkanwar.com/work
https://sayamkanwar.com/about
https://www.facebook.com/sayamkanwar
https://github.com/sayamkanwar
https://codepen.io/sayamk/
https://medium.com/@sayamkanwar/
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

EDIT: Using only builtin modules:

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser

url = 'https://sayamkanwar.com/'

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag=='a':
            attrs = dict(attrs)
            if 'href' in attrs and attrs['href'].startswith('https'):
                print(attrs['href'])

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
   src = response.read().decode('utf-8')

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(src)
```

Prints:

```
https://sayamkanwar.com/work
https://sayamkanwar.com/about
https://www.facebook.com/sayamkanwar
https://github.com/sayamkanwar
https://codepen.io/sayamk/
https://medium.com/@sayamkanwar/
```

Comment: hey! thanks a lot but i want to use internal libraries only. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: He want to do this with regex

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I just use [`request`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

```py
import re
import requests

URL = 'https://sayamkanwar.com/'
response = requests.get(URL)
pattern = r'(a href=")((https):((//)|(\\\\))+([\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&](#!)?)*)"'
all_url = re.findall(pattern, response.text)
for url in all_url:
    print(url[1])
```

**Output:**

```sh
https://www.facebook.com/sayamkanwar
https://github.com/sayamkanwar
https://codepen.io/sayamk/
https://medium.com/@sayamkanwar/
```

**Visual output of the regex:**

[image]

Comment: Please, don't parse HTML with regex. What if text containing `https://...` is inspide <p> tag or somewehere else?

Comment: Yes @AndrejKesely, but the question owner need to do this only using `regex`. That's why I post this solution. I don't know why I get downvote for this solution, hmm...

Comment: @KushanGunasekera thank you so much mate! working well for me :)

Comment: just get it @AndrejKesely, thanks to notify me. Really appreciate, please check it, now only display URLs with `<a href="some_url">`. Thank you sir!

Comment: I updated the code @RachitGupta, now display URL only with `<a href="some_url">` thanks to @AndrejKesely. If this helpful for you please select this answer as accepted one by clicking the correct button below the votes of this answer. Thank you too!